# Django post_delete instance is still present in the database

Tags: django, django-models, signals

One of the keyword argument in he post_delete is the instance, which is the actual instance being deleted.

According to the django docs - [Note that the object will no longer be in the database, so be very careful what you do with this instance.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#pre-save:%7E:text=Note%20that%20the%20object%20will%20no%20longer%20be%20in%20the%20database%2C%20so%20be%20very%20careful%20what%20you%20do%20with%20this%20instance.)

I am testing the following code ->

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Dummy)
def post_delete_callback(**kwargs):
    print('inside post_delete ----------')
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    raise Exception('Exception from the post delete receiver')
```

But even after the exception, the object should be deleted in the database, but **I am getting the exception, as well as the object is not getting deleted from the database**.

In case of pre_delete signal this is justifiable, but what is with the post_save signal? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

The deletion process executes in a [***`atomic`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) block - which means, either this will be executed successfully or will revert back to the previous state(just like nothing has happened!).

In your case, the `Exception` statement creates a blocker to the execution flow and the DB/Django reverts the action (ie, the delete action) to the original state. This makes the objects still not deleted in the DB.

If you remove the `Exception` statement from your signal, you will not see the object again in the Database.